# Symfony 3 FB Login - After OAuth Login flow I go back at Login page because the authentication expires instantly

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, symfony

I am trying to implement Facebook Connect in a web-site. However when I go through the connect process I am returned to Login page page because the authentication expires instantly.
I also have a separate regular registration and login present

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\GiftBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Generator\UrlGeneratorInterface;

class FacebookConnectController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/connect/facebook", name="connect_facebook")
     */
    public function connectFacebookAction(Request $request)
    {

        // redirect to Facebook
        $facebookOAuthProvider = $this->get('app.facebook_provider');
        $url = $facebookOAuthProvider->getAuthorizationUrl([
            // these are actually the default scopes
            'scope' => ['public_profile', 'email'],
            //'redirect_uri' => [$redir],
        ]);

        return $this->redirect($url);
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/connect/facebook-check", name="connect_facebook_check")
     */
    public function connectFacebookActionCheck()
    {
        // will not be reached!
    }
}
```

Facebook Authenticator:

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\GiftBundle\Security;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Guard\AbstractGuardAuthenticator;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Exception\AuthenticationException;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserProviderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Vendor\GiftBundle\Entity\Logins;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Security;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\UsernamePasswordToken;

class FacebookAuthenticator extends AbstractGuardAuthenticator
{
    private $container;

    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container)
    {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function getCredentials(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->getPathInfo() != '/connect/facebook-check') {
            // skip authentication unless we're on this URL!
            return null;
        }
        if ($code = $request->query->get('code')) {
            return $code;
        }
        // no code! Something went wrong. Quite probably the user denied our app access
        // you could read the error, error_code, error_description, error_reason query params
        // http://localhost:8000/connect/facebook-check?error=access_denied&error_code=200&error_description=Permissions+error&error_reason=user_denied&state=S2fKgHJSZSJM0Qs2fhKL6USZP50KSBHc#_=_

        throw CustomAuthenticationException::createWithSafeMessage(
            'There was an error getting access from Facebook. Please try again.'
        );
    }

    public function getUser($authorizationCode, UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        //$user = new Logins();
        $facebookProvider = $this->container->get('app.facebook_provider');
        try {
            // the credentials are really the access token
            $accessToken = $facebookProvider->getAccessToken(
                'authorization_code',
                ['code' => $authorizationCode]
            );
        } catch (IdentityProviderException $e) {
            // probably the authorization code has been used already
            $response = $e->getResponseBody();
            $errorCode = $response['error']['code'];
            $message = $response['error']['message'];
            throw CustomAuthenticationException::createWithSafeMessage(
                'There was an error logging you into Facebook - code '.$errorCode
            );

        }

        /** @var FacebookUser $facebookUser */
        $facebookUser = $facebookProvider->getResourceOwner($accessToken);
        $email = $facebookUser->getEmail();

        //$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        //$check = $em->getRepository('VendorGiftBundle:Logins')->findByEmail($email);

        $em = $this->container->get('doctrine')->getManager();
        // 1) have they logged in with Facebook before? Easy!
        $existingUser = $em->getRepository('VendorGiftBundle:Logins')
            ->findOneBy(array('fbid' => $facebookUser->getId()));
        if ($existingUser) {
            return $existingUser;
        }
        // 2) do we have a matching user by email?
        $user = $em->getRepository('VendorGiftBundle:Logins')
                    ->findOneBy(array('email' => $email));
        // 3) no user? Perhaps you just want to create one
        //      or maybe you want to redirect to a registration (in that case, keep reading_
        if (!$user) {
            $user = new Logins();
            $user->setEmail($email);
            $user->setFirstname($facebookUser->getFirstName());
            $user->setLastname($facebookUser->getLastName());
            $user->setCity($facebookUser->getLocale());
            $user->setCreationtime();
            $user->setStatus(1);
            // set an un-encoded password, which basically makes it *not* possible
            // to login with any password
            $user->setPassword('no password');
        }
        // make sure the Facebook user is set
        $user->setFbid($facebookUser->getId());
        $em->persist($user);
        $em->flush();
        return $user;
        /*
        if(!$check){
            $hash = uniqid();
            //Encode the password (you could also do this via Doctrine listener)
            $password = $this->get('security.password_encoder')
                ->encodePassword($user, $hash);
            $user->setEmail($email);
            $user->setFirstname($facebookUser->getFirstName());
            $user->setLastname($facebookUser->getLastName());
            $user->setCity($facebookUser->getLocale());
            $user->setPassword($password);
            $user->setCreationtime();
            $user->setStatus(1);
            // 4) save the User!
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
            $em->persist($user);
            $em->flush();
            return $user;
        }
        return $user;
         * 
         */
    }

    public function checkCredentials($credentials, UserInterface $user)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationFailure(Request $request, AuthenticationException $exception)
    {
        // this would happen if something went wrong in the OAuth flow
        $request->getSession()->set(Security::AUTHENTICATION_ERROR, $exception);
        $url = $this->container->get('router')
            ->generate('login_route');
        return new RedirectResponse($url);
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
    {
        $key = '_security.main.target_path'; #where "main" is your firewall name

        //check if the referrer session key has been set 
        if ($this->container->get('session')->has($key)) {
            //set the url based on the link they were trying to access before being authenticated
            $url = $this->container->get('session')->get($key);

            //remove the session key
            $this->container->get('session')->remove($key);
        }
        //if the referrer key was never set, redirect to a default route
        else{
            $url = $this->container->get('router')->generate('home_page');

        }

        return new RedirectResponse($url); 
        // todo - remove needing this crazy thing
        /*
        $targetPath = $request->getSession()->get('_security.'.$providerKey.'.target_path');

        if ($targetPath) { 
            $router = $this->container->get('router');
            $targetPath = $router->generate('home_page');
        }
        return new RedirectResponse($targetPath);
         * 
         */
    }

    public function supportsRememberMe()
    {
        return true;
    }



    /**
     * Called when an anonymous user tries to access an protected page.
     *
     * In our app, this is never actually called, because there is only *one*
     * "entry_point" per firewall and in security.yml, we're using
     * app.form_login_authenticator as the entry point (so it's start() method
     * is the one that's called).
     */
    public function start(Request $request, AuthenticationException $authException = null)
    {
        // not called in our app, but if it were, redirecting to the
        // login page makes sense
        $url = $this->container->get('router')
            ->generate('home_page');
        return new RedirectResponse($url);

    }

    protected function getDefaultSuccessRedirectUrl()
    {
        return $this->container->get('router')->generate('home_page');
    }

    protected function getLoginUrl()
    {
        return $this->container->get('router')->generate('login_route');
    }

    public function getDoctrine()
    {
        return $this->container->get('doctrine');
    }

    public function get($id)
    {
        return $this->container->get($id);
    }

}
```

Security.yml:

```
security:

    # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#where-do-users-come-from-user-providers

    encoders:
        Vendor\GiftBundle\Entity\Logins:
            algorithm: bcrypt
            cost: 13
        Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User:
            algorithm: bcrypt
            cost: 13

    #make admin inherit user access
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
#        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    #provider of user authetification name, in our case, email
    providers:
        doctrine1:
            entity: 
                class: Vendor\GiftBundle\Entity\Logins
                property: email
#        in_memory:
#            memory: ~


    firewalls:
        # disables authentication for assets and the profiler, adapt it according to your needs
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        main:
            #pattern: ^/.*
            #security: false
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                login_path: /login
                check_path: /login_check
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
                username_parameter: _email
            provider: doctrine1

            logout:
                path: /logout
                target: /

            anonymous: ~
            guard:
                authenticators:
                    - app.facebook_authenticator
                #entry_point: app.form_login_authenticator
            #anonymous:    ~
            # activate different ways to authenticate

            # http_basic: ~
            # http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/security.html#a-configuring-how-your-users-will-authenticate

            # form_login: ~
            # http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login_setup.html

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/connect, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/login, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/reset, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/sec, role: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Comment: I've tried to debug step by step what happens in the background with the profiler. After I get the code and check the user Guard authenticates successfully, and after I send the user to home_page for example there an exception is encountered instantly which says authentification has expired. Any idea why it expires instantly?

`The security token was removed due to an AccountStatusException.
Context: { "exception": "Object(Symfony\\Component\\Security\\Core\\Exception\\AuthenticationExpiredException)" }`

Answer (score 2):

Setting the token manually is not the correct solution - it's a work around for a deeper issue. The tl;dr is that there is an issue serializer your User object, which causes Symfony to think that the User object has changed on the first request after logging in, and then it logs you out.

The fix is (depending on your app) to remove any custom serialize() method you have on your User object or remove the AdvancedUserInterface from User (and the corresponding methods & properties). A longer explanation can be found here: https://symfonycasts.com/blog/KnpUOAuth2ClientBundle#comment-4662612127

Cheers!

Comment: By not correct - what is the problem with Enk solution? Just that it adds unnecessary code or makes some security issue?

Comment: Another fix which worked is to add $this->isAccountNonLocked to serialize and unserialize functions of user object.

Answer (score 0):

I generated token manually.

```
public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token, $providerKey)
{
    $token = new UsernamePasswordToken($token->getUser(), null, $providerKey, $token->getUser()->getRoles());
    $this->tokenStorage->setToken($token);
    $request->getSession()->set('_security_main', serialize($token));

    $url = $this->router->generate("homepage");

    return new RedirectResponse($url);
}
```

Try this. Dont forget to inject TokenStorage.

Comment: Is this not introducing some security hole? This is not in the example here https://github.com/knpuniversity/oauth2-client-bundle